# Jhipster[5.x.x] project upgrade jdk-8 to jdk 11

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, java-11

I want to upgrade my 5 years old jhipster project with the latest changes by updating ,

spring boot - 2.0.4.RELEASE
jdk 8
jhipster-dependency - 2.0.15
firebird - 3.0.9 [does not support jdk 17]

my dependency

```
<!-- Dependency versions -->
    <jhipster-dependencies.version>2.0.15</jhipster-dependencies.version>
    <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <!-- The hibernate version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
    <hibernate.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.version>
    <!-- The javassist version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/${hibernate.version} -->
    <javassist.version>3.22.0-GA</javassist.version>
    <!-- The liquibase version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
    <liquibase.version>3.5.5</liquibase.version>
    <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
    <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</mapstruct.version>`
```

spring boot version changes are not reflecting in the project logs

I have used to update it by auto jhipster way update but no luck as my project version too back.

I tried manual by by changing the dependency to latest but no luck.

Is there any proper or structural way, So that I can update my project to the latest jdk-11

======================
**new updates**

Actually, I have updated the below version which will support jdk11.

```
<!-- Dependency versions -->
    <jhipster-dependencies.version>3.0.1</jhipster-dependencies.version>
    <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <!-- The hibernate version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
    <hibernate.version>5.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    <!-- The javassist version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/${hibernate.version} -->
    <javassist.version>3.23.1-GA</javassist.version>
    <!-- The liquibase version should match the one managed by
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
    <liquibase.version>3.6.3</liquibase.version>
    <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
    <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
```

But however, when I run the application the logs says, I still using spring boot 2.0.4, but I have updated to 2.1.4.RELEASE in pom file

the log says below
**The Class-Path manifest attribute in org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.5\liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:...m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar**

2023-08-29 17:12:53.969 DEBUG 4256 --- [  restartedMain]          : Running with **Spring Boot v2.0.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.8.RELEASE**

Comment: What happens if you use JDK 11 to compile your project? Does the enforcer plugin prevent you from using it? If so, adjust the versions in your pom.xml to allow Java 11.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Matt Raible

In order to use the jdk11, I have to update the spring boot version, hipster, liquibase, hibernate, etc

I have updated the question with the latest findings/changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the Spring Boot version in the `pom.xml` does not override what's in the jhipster-bom file. I know this from experience. I'm not sure if there's a way to override bom properties.

Comment: Get rid of jhipster-dependencies in your pom.xml and manage yourself your spring-boot dependencies, you'll get full control. Depending on JHipster for this just makes your life more complex to fix vulnerabilities for no real benefit as your project is too far behind JHipster.

Comment: Thanks @MattRaible and Gaël Marziou,
I have tried to remove the hipster dependency but it seems there are many configs, java files, angular files generated and used jhipster classes and their functionalities, etc.

Also, I have tried with new spring boot app with the latest version but moving the src code from my original application to the new project got many changes as well because as I said its all integrated with jhipster.

Comment: I had a similar experience when upgrading from JHipster 5 to 7. I ended up rewriting the app from scratch as part of https://jhipster-book.org v7.